# vagrant vm not starting after adding storage device

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, disk, vagrantfile

I want to create vm using vagrant with 2 disks. vm is showing error on gui "FATAL: Could not read from boot medium". It runs fine if created without any disk any disk.
Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.define "cn1" do |cn1|
            cn1.vm.box = "trusty"
            cn1.vm.hostname = "cn1"
            cn1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.100.11"
            cn1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.10.11"
            cn1.vm.host_name = "controller1"
            cn1.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
                    vb.memory = 500
                    vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine1_disk0", "--size", "8192"]
                    vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine1_disk1", "--size", "8192"]
                    vb.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "SATA Controller", "--remove"]
                    vb.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "SATA Controller", "--add", "sata"]
                    vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "1", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine1_disk0.vdi"]
                    vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "2", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine1_disk1.vdi"]
                    vb.gui = true
            end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualBox is telling you that you cannot boot from your disk.

If you open VirtualBox and look at the settings of your VM, under storage, you'll find that you have your 2 disks as you declared but the base image is not attached.

If you now look on your file system (location depends on your OS, I am on mac) for this VM

```
fhenri@machine:~/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/trusty_cn1_1454620633289_44965$ ll
total 3174824
drwx------   6 fhenri  staff         204  4 fév 22:17 .
drwxr-xr-x  12 fhenri  staff         408  4 fév 22:17 ..
drwx------   3 fhenri  staff         102  4 fév 22:17 Logs
-rw-------   1 fhenri  staff  1625489408  4 fév 22:19 box-disk1.vmdk
-rw-------   1 fhenri  staff        8488  4 fév 22:17 trusty_cn1_1454620633289_44965.vbox
-rw-------   1 fhenri  staff        8143  4 fév 22:17 trusty_cn1_1454620633289_44965.vbox-prev
```

so vagrant has imported the box in the `box-disk1.vmdk` but you have removed this disk and added 2 blank disk so you cannot boot.

If you remove those 2 lines

```
            vb.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "SATAController", "--remove"]
            vb.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "SATAController", "--add", "sata"]
```

Then the disk remains attached to the VM and you can boot.

Now if you open the VM settings in VirtualBox, you'll find 3 disks (under the SATA Controller):

- box-disk1.vmdk
- machine1_disk0.vdi
- machine1_disk1.vdi